# Facebook Premissions View not showing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I create an application integrate Facebook in it. After first login it shows Permissions  screen in which it take rights from user. But after sign out and re-sign then it does not show any permissions view i want that it should show on each login. How can i achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to revoke the permissions to get this permissions screen to re-appear.  To do that, you could add a logout button and then you would issue an HTTP DELETE request to /PROFILE_ID/permissions.  Although from a user perspective this would be mildly annoying to have to approve each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
Once the set of permissions are granted, facebook won't show the permission dialog again.
The only way to display the permission dialog again is to ask for another permission, but in this case, only the new permission will show up in the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to be a feature! After the first time "Accept", Facebook remembers this & next time on, does not ask.